# Conversion of Protein sequence to DNA using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert protein sequence to DNA and have no idea how to do it. I saw quite a few examples on how to solve for DNA to Protein but not for the reverse.

```
    "AAA":"K", "AAC":"N", "ACA":"T", "AGA":"R", "AGC":"S",            
    "AUA":"I", "AUG":"M", "CAA":"Q", "CAC":"H", "CCA":"P",
    "CUA":"L", "GAA":"E", "GAC":"D", "GCA":"A", "GGA":"G",
    "GUA":"V", "UAC":"Y", "UGC":"C", "UGG":"W", "UUC":"F"
```

I want to convert the protein sequence to its corresponding codon.

```py
def translate(seq): 
    table = { 
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M', 
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T', 
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K', 
        'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                  
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L', 
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P', 
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q', 
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R', 
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V', 
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A', 
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E', 
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G', 
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S', 
        'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L', 
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_', 
        'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W', 
    } 
    protein ="" 
    if len(seq)%3 == 0: 
        for i in range(0, len(seq), 3): 
            codon = seq[i:i + 3] 
            protein+= table[codon] 
    return protein
```

The code above is for translating DNA to Protein, I need the reverse.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hello. Give us an example of input and expected output, to make it clear, please.

Comment: Isn't the reverse *simpler* than the code you already wrote?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs an answer, the following function gives a list of all DNA sequences that translate into a given protein sequence.

Be careful though, as a short protein sequence (10+ amino acids) can yield tens (if not hundreds) of thousands of possible DNA sequences.

```py
import itertools as it

def back_translate_to_dna(aa_sequence: str) -> list:

    back_translation_code = {
        'A': ['GCA', 'GCC', 'GCG', 'GCT'],
        'C': ['TGT', 'TGC'],
        'D': ['GAC', 'GAT'],
        'E': ['GAG', 'GAA'],
        'F': ['TTT', 'TTC'],
        'G': ['GGT', 'GGG', 'GGA', 'GGC'],
        'H': ['CAT', 'CAC'],
        'I': ['ATC', 'ATA', 'ATT'],
        'K': ['AAG', 'AAA'],
        'L': ['CTT', 'CTG', 'CTA', 'CTC', 'TTA', 'TTG'],
        'M': ['ATG'],
        'N': ['AAC', 'AAT'],
        'P': ['CCT', 'CCG', 'CCA', 'CCC'],
        'Q': ['CAA', 'CAG'],
        'R': ['AGG', 'AGA', 'CGA', 'CGC', 'CGG', 'CGT'],
        'S': ['AGC', 'AGT', 'TCT', 'TCG', 'TCC', 'TCA'],
        'T': ['ACA', 'ACG', 'ACT', 'ACC'],
        'V': ['GTA', 'GTC', 'GTG', 'GTT'],
        'W': ['TGG'],
        'Y': ['TAT', 'TAC'],
        '*': ['TAA', 'TGA', 'TAG']
    }

    list_of_list_of_codons = [back_translation_code[aa] for aa in aa_sequence]
    list_of_combinations = [''.join(combination) for combination in it.product(*list_of_list_of_codons)]
    
    return list_of_combinations
    

list_of_dna_sequences = back_translate_to_dna('MHH')
```